# Wingpanel and system app not repsondong

Tags: wingpanel, system, plank, startup, sudo

Using for several months. Now wingpanel got stuck after a min from loading and during that a notification will appear network not connected.
After that most of the system app will not respond and sudo command will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

Access the terminal and reset the desktop settings
Access the terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1 and type:

$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop